# Is this RC Snubber functional?

Tags: triac, snubber, leakage-current

I had made this circuit which is basically works somehow as a UPS (when there is a power failure from the mains (220 VAC) the inverter line turns on and keeps the load on) and yes I had tested the circuit there was no fire or magic smoke (without the snubber). But would this Snubber be ok or I should put it on all the 4 TRIACs? And if it was like in the schematic would it cause any harmful leakage or any other problem?
[image]

Note:

The load is changeable; I mean it could be resistive, inductive or capacitive.

Maximum current consumption is 5 A with 220 VAC.

Warning! anybody tries to implement this circuit, make sure that you use a Snubberless triacs because normal triacs (like bt136) can have a small On state period (for a fraction of a second) so this can cause a fire/smoke/popping fuse etc... because the 2 lines may get connected.

Comment: Ah, so the four TRIACs are so that two separate sources can be used for a given load? What kind of loads would be used?

Comment: Correct. The loads would be different such as motors or PCs(SMPS) even heaters and so on.

Comment: Remmember that triacs can fail short circuit .If this is a hazard then you should back up with mechanical relays that cold switch so will have a very long life.

Comment: Hm, I wonder what the over/under is, on whether the TRIACs on one side pulling in, cause the opposite side(s) to turn on as well (turn-on dV/dt can be high, and RC snubbers have no effect on it). Definitely a good idea to use relays. Can even use multiple relays, with the TRIACs to provide sparkless turn-on, then bypass the TRIACs with hard contacts to eliminate voltage drop (and I suppose, increase fault current capacity).

Comment: @Autistic yes mate I am already trying to build a fault system which contains a current shunt monitored by the MCU so that if the triacs failed the whole system would shutdown

Comment: @TimWilliams actually thought of it but I don't like using relays because I need a very fast turn on so using a relay would just mean to replace the Triacs.

Comment: @TimWilliams, one more thing I forgot to say mate, the Optotriac here is a zero-crossing one so that means the turn on will surely be sparkless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The snubber is used to protect the semiconductors (switches or diodes) from a high dV/dt (rapid voltage changes). If the load is variable, it usually is designed for the worst-case scenario. This will ensure even for the highest inductance, you still have acceptable dV/dt over the Triacs.

You can read more about it here:

[What is Snubber Circuit and How does it work?](https://automationforum.co/what-is-snubber-circuit-and-how-does-it-work/)

There are different types of snubber. The RC one is the simplest and more common one. It needs to be in parallel with the switches to do the job properly. So, I would use four of the RC snubbers, one for each triac.

However, the main reason to have the snubber is to absorb some of the spikes on the voltage that is generated with inductive load. This means, in theory, a snubber in parallel to the load (as shown in your circuit diagram) should do the same.

This online tool helps you calculate the values:

[Snubber Circuit Design Calculators](https://www.daycounter.com/Calculators/Snubbers/Snubber-Design-Calculator.phtml)

Notice that the current in that form is the peak current, not the nominal current. You need to extract that from the load's datasheet. The acceptable "rt" needs to be extracted from Triac's datasheet.

Comment: The triac will only between two states (ON or OFF) it will not be variable but my concern is about the inductive loads epically so I need to make sure if it works decently

Comment: You have to know the range of the loads that will be connected to this circuit. You should calculate the snubber for the highest inductive load that would be connected to this circuit. 
I also would add a varistor with proper voltage in parallel with Triac to absorb any over-voltage spikes. I had some failures with inductive loads without it.

Comment: ah my bad I already had added a MOV in the real design, this one is just to be obvious for you. and yes the highest load is 5 A 250 VAC so how I calculate it for such load?

Comment: I modified the answer and added a useful link to it. Bear in mind that the 5A you mentioned might be the nominal current. The peak current is different and you have to find that to be able to calculate the correct snubber.

Comment: it would be fused with a circuit breaker of 5 A because it will be sold to other people who may connect different loads to it. I am thinking of using a 5 A NTC of 20 ohms so it wastes less power?

Comment: The fuse can withstand higher currents for a very short period of time. The peak current is an inrush current for a very short period of time. It could be a couple of mili-seconds to a couple of seconds. A motor might draw five times more current than the nominal value at startup. You need to check the datasheet of the motor.

Comment: as I've stated, I have no idea about the load that would be connected because it would be used by other guys, so I will calculate it multiplied by three times because I have no constant load for it